# SharePoint Online Custom List -> Link or Picture Column | Is there a way to upload picture directly from New Item Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, column, newform

First of all I am using SharePoint Online with the app "Custom List". In this Custom List I have added a column of the type "link or picture". Basically I use this column for a simple picture view.

When I want to add a new list item to my list, in this column (link or picture) I can only enter the direct URL and the display name of the link, which means I have to upload the picture first (for example to Site Assets) and then post the link to this picture in the column:

> [image]

Is there any possibility, to change the New Item Form in any way, that I can directly upload a picture to this column (in this new item form) without the stated workaround? Is it also possible to steer, that the pictures added via new list item forms are standardly stored in the Site Assets?

(I know there is an extra picture library app, but in my case the picture should be just an extra info to the list item and not the main motif.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable publishing and use a [`Publishing Image`-Column.](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-publishing-columns-to-content-types-lists-or-libraries-4e268d2e-4822-4bc6-a992-88287119a052)

This gives you a nice UI to browse and select images, format them a little or lets you upload new images.

[image]

Comment: Hello Nils :) Thank you very much for your answer. Where do I enable "publishing"? I checked in my websitefeatures, but unfortunately it is not listed there.

Comment: Two Features: "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" in SiteCollection-Features and after that "SharePoint Server Publishing" in Site-Features

Comment: So give me please some time to get back to you, as I am unfortunately not SiteCollection-Admin. Will contact the responsible person and ask for activation of this feature :)

Comment: Thanks, worked fine for me :)